# Implenting (generic, not C++)interface-like behaviour with headers

Tags: c, design-patterns, embedded

I'm attempting to create some sort of code superstructure in an (embedded) C context, which would allow me to swap in and out underlying implementations of the code itself while preserving a certain defined interface. I'm not sure how best to describe what I'm trying to, so I'll instead put up a small example:

interface.h:

```
(#pragma once or other include guard scheme)

/**
 * 'Standard' include file, implementation 
 * independent. Mostly contains
 * Declarations, specifying function name, 
 * return values, parameters, types, etc. 
 */
static void do_something(void); 
static void do_something_else(void); 

//Subsequently includes the actual header for the 
//specific implementation to be used

#include "implementation.h"
```

implementation.h:

```
(#pragma once or other include guard scheme)

/**
 * Include file, implementation specific.
 * Mostly contains implementation specific 
 * defines. The function prototypes are 
 * obtained from the interface.h include.
 * However, some implementations need to be
 * static inline for performance issues, and 
 * are defined here.
 */
static inline void do_something(void) {
    implementation_of_something;
}
```

implementation.c:

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "implementation.h"

/**
 * Actual implementations of the rest of the 
 * functions.
 */
static void do_something_else(void) {
    implementation_of_something_else;
}
```

And finally, user.c:

```
#include interface.h

int main(void){    
   do_something();
   do_something_else();
}
```

The desired outcome is that when main.c is compiled and the executable is linked, the `do_something()` call gets inlined into `main()`, while `do_something_else()` results in implementation.o being linked in and a function call taking place.

Largely, this seems to work.

My questions, though, are the following:

- Is this an acceptable way of doing things? Is there a better way to be doing this? Any other more appropriate pattern?
- The function prototypes are different in different places. Specifically for the case of `do_something()`, which in one case is `static void` and the other is `static inline void`. `Doxygen` certainly seems to have some issue with this, I'm not sure if the compiler does. Does it have any consequences? Is there a way to avoid this?

EDIT: Supplementary questions:

- How would the compiler behave if it found the following in a translation unit:

Case 1:

```
extern void function(void);                (from interface.h)
static inline void function(void){         (from implementation.h)
        function_body;
}

function();                                (from user.c)
```

Comment: FWIW, you can #include '.c' files, not just header files.  Just create the appropriate `#define` and `#ifdef` to make the appropriate ones `static inline` when the .c file is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your post whether ***Implenting (generic, not C++)interface-like behaviour with headers*** is a requirement. If it is not, I would change the strategy a little bit.

**interface.h:**

Make the functions `extern` instead of `static`.

```
extern void do_something(void); 
extern void do_something_else(void);
```

**interface.c:**

Implement the functions declared in `intereface.h` in terms the implementations provided in `implementation.h`.

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "implementation.h"

static void do_something(void) {
    implementation_of_something();
}

static void do_something_else(void) {
    imlementation_of_something_else();
}
```

**implementation.h:**

Make the implementation functions also `extern` instead of `static`.

```
extern void implementation_of_something(void);
extern void imlementation_of_something_else(void);
```

**implementation.c:**

The real implementations of the functions.

```
#include "implementation.h"

void implementation_of_something(void) {
   //... The implementation
}

void implementation_of_something_else(void) {
   //... The implementation
}
```

**user.c:**

```
#include "interface.h"

int main(void){    
   do_something();
   do_something_else();
}
```

This change reduces the dependency of `implementation.h` to only one file. If you swap the implementation, the .c files that depend on `interface.h` don't have to be recompiled.

Comment: That would work if all the member functions of the implementation could be linked in. The origin of the problem, from what I've gathered from looking at various tutorials etc, is that the implementations are sometimes (but not always - could be true for some function in implementation A but not in some other implementation B) inlined - the function call is more expensive to me than compile time.

Comment: The implementations -- `implementation_of_something` and `implementation_of_something_else` -- can be inlined without impacting users of `interface.h`. I would strongly encourage moving implementations of `do_something` and `do_something_else` to `interface.c`.

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers are used to bring OO into C world. Idea is have a single function like:

```
do(function pointer to desired implementation){
...
}
```

so in your main program you only call do(), but depending on situation, the argument being passed to it -here a pointer to function that's implementing it- is different. Search for function pointer object oriented, it's an established practice.